# How to replicate CouchDB local to remote with nano -- without duplication?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-nano, iriscouch

I'm attempting to replicate my local CouchDB database with a remote database that lives on iriscouch.com. I'm using [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano/).

This works fine -- except that the local documents are **added** to the existing iriscouch database rather than the local database being replicated on the remote.

Am I missing something?

Relevant code below.

```
nano.db.replicate(localCouchName, remoteCouchName,
  function(error, body) {
    if (error) {
    console.log('nano.db.replicate() error:', error);
    } else {
      console.log('nano.db.replicate() success', body);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replication is an additive operation, not a replacing operation. If you want your state on the remote to be exactly like the local state without any regard for what's currently on the remote node, you should probably just remove the database on the remote node prior to doing the replication.